# google scripts: copy data between sheets in worksheet - copyTo() not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy

The script I'm using was contributed on git.  It is designed to over write each days data.  I want to copy the data at the end of each day and write it to another sheet to archive it.  I can create the named sheet and capture the data, but I am having issues pasting the data into the new sheet.

```
function archiveSheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("copy_of_inverter_data");
  var sheetSiteInfo = ss.getSheetByName("details");

  //set archive sheet name
  var currentDate = Utilities.formatDate(sheetSiteInfo.getRange("B5").getValue(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");
  var nextSheet = "id_"+currentDate;
  // create sheet with current date
  ss.insertSheet(nextSheet);
  Logger.log(currentDate);
  Logger.log(nextSheet);

  //copy data to new sheet
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  var destination = ss.getSheetByName(nextSheet);

  Logger.log(range);
  Logger.log(data);
  Logger.log(sheet);

  range.copyTo(nextSheet);//This line not working
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
range.copyTo(nextSheet);
```

Should be:

```
range.copyTo(destination.getRange("A1"));
```

You are using `copyTo(range)`  The parameter needed is a range.  You are using `nextSheet` for the parameter, which is a string, not a range.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks for the fix and the explanation.  Cheers!